# Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory order by RunEnd not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

HI i am using Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory to get latest pipleline RunEnd(datetime).
body of my request looking like following.

```
{
 "lastUpdatedAfter":"2020-07-05",
 "lastUpdatedBefore":"2020-11-16",
 "Orderby":[{"RunEnd"}],
 "filters":[{"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"Equals","values":["abc"]}]
}
```

When i added orderby then filter for pipelinName is not working(otherwise filter is working) and RunEnd sorted by default descending order but i need it in ascending order and dont have any syntax available in microsoft artical.

So i need

1. syntax of order by acending and also working filter for piplelineName.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the answer. 
{
  "lastUpdatedAfter":"@{adddays(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),-60)}",
  "lastUpdatedBefore":"@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}",
  "filters":[
             {"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"Equals","values": 
              ["insighthealth_npi_at_move_to_bronze"]
             },
            ],
  "orderBy":[{"orderBy":"RunEnd","order":"DESC"}]
 }
```